# Java Generics extending two classes with an enum involved

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm attempting to make an interface for user-defined Enums to implement, so that they can all utilize a common ConfigurationLoader class for their configuration values, however I cannot seem to declare a `Class<?>` variable that extends two subclasses in the method arguments (jdk 1.8, static methods are possible in interfaces).

The reason I need to have both is I want to be able to guaruntee that the enum does in fact implement the `ConfigMarker` interface, but is also an Enum in which I can call `values()` on. How can I make it understand that it has two subclasses?

```
public interface ConfigMarker {

    public String getPath();

    public Object getDefault();

    public static void setDefaults(FileConfiguration file, Class<? extends Enum & ConfigMarker> clazz) {
        try {
            Method m = clazz.getMethod("values");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            for (ConfigMarker conf : (ConfigMarker[]) m.invoke(null)) {
                if (!file.isSet(conf.getPath())) {
                    file.set(conf.getPath(), conf.getDefault());
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            // numerous other exceptions that are caught, irrelevant.    
        }
    }

}
```

The specific compile-time error states "Wrong number of type arguments, 1 expected". I know that it is possible to specify more than one with `&`, so why is it failing here?

## Edit

Per the answer below, I was able to resolve the type, but I cannot seem to make a call to the method itself:

```
public enum ConfigValue implements ConfigMarker {...}

public ConfigurationLoader(Main project, ConfigMarker marker) {
    //...
    marker.setDefaults(file, ConfigValue.SOME_VALUE.getDeclaringClass());
    //or
    marker.setDefaults(file, ConfigValue.class);
}
```

Comment: Well, `ConfigValue` does not seem to be an enum to me

Comment: Typing error, however it was just another silly mistake (I didn't call it staticly. Everything works now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to declare a type variable on your *method*:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & ConfigMarker> void setDefaults(FileConfiguration cfg, Class<T> c)
```

(note: `Enum<T>` is a hunch from my part)

Comment: You were quicker than me :P

Comment: By the way. after fixing this error, there's another compiler error.

Comment: This seemed to have worked! However I'm not seeing any compiler error per @LuiggiMendoza 's comment.

Comment: Aha, I'm seeing it now, it's in attempting to call the method itself.

Comment: Just as a side note: if this class is only meant to be used by enums you could declare it as `ConfigMarker<E extends Enum<E> & ConfigMarker<E>>`